# Alexa Service unable to call Access Token URI in Alexa Account Linking

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

When I try account linking from Alexa web app, I get error 'unable to link your skill'. following is my work progress.

I have Provided following URI for auth and accesstoken URI:-

Authorization URI: https://[My AuthServer APP URL:PORT]/auth/authorize

Access Token URI:  https://[My AuthServer APP URL:PORT]/auth/token

1. Alexa app is able to open my authentication url.
2. I am able to authorize and provide authorization code with redirect uri.
3. Alexa fails in this step to link with my skill. It say's 'Unable to link your skill'.
4. It is not even calling my api for access and refresh token

Redirect URI Format https://layla.amazon.com/api/skill/link/**********?state=A2SAAEAEAuglqkkHrQ2dx9KcQKveKgBsNCS0Ijx0oKQfUmcMbaXm6nc7rfQEaLns1iv3aRue6PqvYjr8yVzJcaCtC8OPVm6tCfbT-9lOYh0VPujQwp0JRa9-gJpKqN4Ny0eCIMFvdYeQT2SsII-oC8siTPxF5UNhXR2-No4VqhqelOZHHNe5BXs91roaLtAAtJrv9vb-W5c3QSSZpFuXRFopJHmtYVc4so5dIyG09aU7CEcTCybqQ735chV9BwLR6LvYxrniUERhR8-IyPmJcV60_FJ-pOVEAiHOl4jEhZG08KvoIFa1SELf8WLgmbIbdb4a14EAqEtNv5nDJaST9m12MF_EM8j5De4MJmMssncG3AVcRzK_j4qSSdaZuoetQ-QYemb2R0QPh0zssGeT9DMdszkSCWo4krA5eCXNeOEmp4JNCJjwThuT4vwhoz0rFu8Pdz5SaCzwQ1ushRTYLwun4-asdn682C8Dml52ifQ&code=******************************************

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you find an answer?????? I've been having the same issue and haven't been able to find an answer!

Comment: I have getting same error how to resolve it??? I need argent solution.